# too big distance between the lines in a table with Arabic letters

Tags: longtable, line-spacing, arabic

I use the package `semtrans` in order to print Arabic letters in a Table in my document.

My problem is that line spacing between two lines of Arabic letters (probably because of the used font) in the output is too large in the table. I tried the command `\singlespacing` but the space is still too big.

Here my example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{semtrans}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ | m{3cm} | m{3cm}| m{3cm} | m{3cm} | } 
\hline
\textbf{Transliteration} & \textbf{Arabic Letter} & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{IPA Symbol}  \\
\hline  
\Alif & \begin{RLtext}"' \end{RLtext} \setarab& \textit{hamza} & \textglotstop \\ 
\hline
\textit{\={a} / a /u / i}  & \begin{RLtext}A \end{RLtext} \setarab &\textit{\Alif alif \textsubdot{t}aw\={\i}la} & a: / a / u / i \\
\hline

\textit{\^{a}}& \begin{RLtext}Y\end{RLtext} \setarab &\textit{\Alif alif maq\textsubdot{s}\={u}ra} & a: \\
\hline
\textit{b}& \begin{RLtext}b \end{RLtext}\setarab &\textit{b\={a}\Alif} & b \\
\hline
\textit{t}&\begin{RLtext}t \end{RLtext}\setarab &\textit{t\={a}\Alif} & t \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Does someone have any idea, how to make the distance smaller?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your verbal description of the issue is compatible with many kinds of inputs, and thus doesn't help narrow down the cause(s) of the problem. Please provide a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001)
 that generates the problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: By the way, no need to encase a `longtable` enviroment inside a `center` environment -- a `longtable` is automatically centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `RLtext` environment to insert arabic text you can use `\RL{arabic text}` for inserting short arabic text inside latin paragraphs.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{semtrans}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tipa}

\setarab
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ |m{3cm}|m{3cm}|m{3cm}|m{3cm}| } 
\hline
\textbf{Transliteration} & \textbf{Arabic Letter} & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{IPA Symbol}  \\
\hline  
\Alif & \RL{"'} & \textit{hamza} & \textglotstop \\ 
\hline
\textit{\={a} / a /u / i}  & \RL{A}  &\textit{\Alif alif \textsubdot{t}aw\={\i}la} & a: / a / u / i \\
\hline

\textit{\^{a}}& \RL{Y} &\textit{\Alif alif maq\textsubdot{s}\={u}ra} & a: \\
\hline
\textit{b}& \RL{b} &\textit{b\={a}\Alif} & b \\
\hline
\textit{t}& \RL{t} &\textit{t\={a}\Alif} & t \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a part-solution, by adding 
    `\usepackage{setspace}`to the preamble and adding `\begin{spacing}{.6}` before and `\end{spacing}`after the table. Now I need only to disable this command for the first row of the table. Any ideas how it can be done? Thank you!